# Typescript allow extension of AxiosConfig

Tags: typescript, axios

I have an interface extend AxiosRequestConfig, but when I run get method, it reports an error, I have to use as AxiosRequestConfig.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You have an `interface` that extends `AxiosRequestConfig`. And from the code image, it seems to me that you have added property `silenceLoad: boolean`.

But here you have to understand, when you extend some interface, it doesn't change that interface but just creates a new interface that you can use anywhere, that means `AxiosRequestConfig` still don't have any property named `silenceLoad`.

> So when you're calling the method `axios.get`, it is checking the type against `AxiosRequestConfig` that don't have any `silenceLoad`, not against your extended interface, which is mentioned in your error.

Comment: What do you want to do? Do you want to send `silenceLoad` data to your server or what?

Comment: ##  I found a solution   declare module 'axios' {
  export interface AxiosRequestConfig {
 
    silenceLoad?: boolean;
  }